# Должны ли стоять запятые вокруг слова "особенно"?

Tags: синтаксис

"Важную роль в местоположении и общей композиции Внутреннего и особенно Запретного города играло учение о середине".

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что слово "особенно" здесь вводное, поэтому запятые вокруг него нужны, хотя не уверен на все 100 - тут от текста и смысла может зависеть, поскольку запятые могут изменить смысл предложения. А перед второй буквой "и", т. е. после слова "Внутреннего" думаю, что нужна запятая.

Comment: 1. Я на 99% уверен, что запятыми слово "особенно" выделять нужно, но не знаю и не могу отыскать нужного правила.
2. А вот в запятой после "Внутреннего" я что-то сомневаюсь.
Уберем, допустим, слово "особенно". Получим: "Важную роль в местоположении и общей композиции Внутреннего и Запретного города играло учение о середине."
Разве нужна здесь запятая?

Comment: Для слова "особенно" правило такое: "Если слово (или словосочетание) содержит в себе дополнительную информацию (можно обойтись и без него), то оно должно выделяться запятыми или находиться в скобках" - насколько я помню. Теперь и я сомневаюсь в запятой после слова "Внутреннего" - как я уже говорил, запятые меняют смысл предложения, так что, если есть сомнения, то нужно попытаться уловить смысл.

Answer (score 0):

Не надо: интуиция!